# boto3 s3 download file, key arg seems redundant to filename

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to understand why there needs to be two arguments here:

1. `key` which is basically the `filename`
2. `path` argument, the path of the file

Isn't it redundant to still pass the key?

Can't we just pass the `bucket` and the `filename`?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`key` in S3 could be a long string, like `/my-prefix/YYYY/MM/DD/UUID.txt`. It can, and usually will, contain things like slash characters. So it makes sense to have to specify the local filename argument separately, because you may not want to save the file in the same path that it is saved in S3, and you also may not want to save it using the same name that was used in S3.

Comment: I misunderstood the context. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the file **to** the `Filename` which has different name than the `Key` **from** where you are downloading, e.g. Key = 'hello.txt', Filename = '/tmp/MylocalCopyOfTheHello.txt'